# invalid symlink error in pycharm python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

Started to learn python a few weeks ago, i made and ran some basic files. all worked well.
At one point i uninstalled python and reinstalled it.
i continued making and running new files no problem.

now i am trying to go back to and run some of my old files and i am getting an error.

```
Error:Cannot run program "/Users/paulthomas/PycharmProjects/plotting/venv/bin/python" (in directory "/Users/paulthomas/PycharmProjects/plotting"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

In pycharm i open the folders and hover over the python file section and it says i have a symlink error. How can i fix it?
i have been using `pipenv` in my newer projects as they are django projects. But this project im trying to get to run is just a basic python project.

[image]

Comment: which platform are you running this on? If you go to that path and do an `ls -l <python>` what do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have reinstalled python, it is likely that the virtual env is linking to the wrong original python binaries.

You can either relink the files (by finding what they should have linked to, and relinking them) or if you have a requirements.txt file for the environment, delete and recreate the virtual env.

You can either do this through pycharm's environments system, or by using:

```
python3 -m venv <your environment name>
```

From your screenshot, your environment name is venv.

If the reinstalled python is a different version, it's likely safer to recreate the virtual env than to try linking things that may end up being inconsistent.

Comment: just to confirm,  i go into the project and delete the `venv` files. then i cd to the project in terminal and do a `pip install venv` into the project?